# Find the points on a bezier curve. (GDI+)

Tags: c#, gdi+, gdi

Can you please help me to accomplish this using c#.

I have a GDI+ call as below:

```
graphics.FillPie(Brushes.White, _
                 new Rectangle(0, 0, 400, 150), 0 - 90, 77.783651160272726f);

graphics.DrawArc(new System.Drawing.Pen(Brushes.Black, 2), _
                 new RectangleF(0, 0, 400, 150), 0 - 90, 77.783651160272726f);
```

**My requirement is  to find all the points along the bezier curve/shape(pie, arc).**

i.e, I need to redraw the shape in my method, which accepts only a **point array**. I have only the rectangle co-ordinates, start angle and sweep angle with me. Can anyone let me know if there is any inbuild method in .net for calculating this or is there any easy method to find this one.

Please let me know if you need any other informations. Kindly help me as this is very critical for me as I am not a genious in Math.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really have to represent this as an array of points?

If you can be flexible on the signature of your method, and instead of `Point[]` accept a `GraphicsPath`, then you can represent this curve in C# by compining the two parts.

**EDIT: Adding example**

For example, you can create a `GraphicsPath` like this:

```
GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
path.AddPie(new Rectangle(0, 0, 400, 150), -90, 77.78f);
path.AddArc(new Rectangle(0, 0, 400, 150), -90, 77.78f);
```

You can later use it to draw graphics using the `Graphics.DrawPath` method, or access the graphics path data through the `GraphicsPath.PathPoints`, `GraphicsPath.PathTypes` and `GraphicsPath.PointCount` properties.

Comment: Can you please explain me in detail, on how to represent it as a graphics path?

Answer (score 3):

I have done the math and created a function called BezierCoordinates in the below given article in code project.

[BezierCurve](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/BezierCurve.aspx)

Its a solution done in C#, Displayed in Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

Add your arc/curve to a GraphicsPath object, use the [Flatten method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fz2042a8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to approximate the Bezier curves in the path as line segments, and use the [PathPoints property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.pathpoints%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to get the array of points.

Comment: The [C++ API documentation for Flatten](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535530.aspx) has an example that exactly matches the question: converting a Bézier curve to points.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some math, but fortunately nothing crazy. This site explains how to draw a circle by calculating points on it:

http://www.nsbasic.com/palm/info/technotes/TN25a.htm

It's not in C# but should give you an idea of how it works. `Math.Sin()` and `Math.Cos()` are .NET's sin and cos methods.